# How can I prevent a random number generator from repeating numbers?

Tags: java, random

How can I prevent a random number generator from repeating numbers?

Here's the part of my code that generates the random numbers:

```
String [] number = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
Random random = new Random();
int Select = random.nextInt(number.length);
System.out.println(number[Select]);
```

Sometimes it repeats numbers, like "4", and then "4" again. I'd like it to be always a different number.

Comment: Everyone please stop using the array of strings. That has no bearing on the aim of the question. This is not a minimal example of how to use Random.nextInt(), and such an example is easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
class Generator {
    List<String> number = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    int n = 0;

    Generator() {
        Collections.shuffle(number);
    }

    String next() {
        return number.get(n++);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a small set of numbers (one that can easily fit in memory), I would:

1. copy the numbers into an `ArrayList<String>`,
2. use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize this list
3. iterate over the values of the list

Comment: or call `remove()` on the list as opposed to iterating over it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution..
I used ArrayList instead of regular array since it's string..

```
import java.util.*;

class RandomWithoutRepeat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>(
         Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6"));
         Random random = new Random();
         int size = number.size();
         int Select = random.nextInt(number.size());
         for(int i =0; i< size; i++)
         {
            Select = random.nextInt(number.size());
            System.out.println(number.get(Select));
            number.remove(Select);   
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it could be:

```
store what values have already been generated in an array x
while new value is in the var x
    generate a new value again
use new value in the way you want
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I am not 100 percent into your code, but it seems as if you are printing out the length of a number, and not the number... why? Are you trying to prevent getting two 4 digit numbers in a row? Ok, I get it... nvm.

edit: ok, so make it so that the array removes the 'select' variable every time the loop is run( make a loop if you don't have it). Then, the number can't possibly be picked.

Comment: The OP is requesting a random number, whose value is not greater than the length of the array (minus 1), then selecting the value from the array that's present at that location. Their algorithm is not *quite* correct, but it's not totally wrong.

Comment: Asking for clarification should be a comment, not an answer.